# Ignore committing a specific directory to git

Tags: git, gitignore

I am aware that giving the path of file or directory in the .gitignore file does not add those files to my git repository, but I wanted to ignore all "build" directories created in my repository, I don't want to specify the complete path of my individual build directory every time. Please suggest the solution.

Comment: First of all, why are your build output folders located inside the `.git` directory in the first place?  I think the cleanest fix here would be to not build into `.git`.  That failing, why can't you just add the various build folders to your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: @tim, my repo contains some small examples in a seperate directory , so each one has CMakeLists.txt file. Thus  build has to be done in the "build" directory for each cmakefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your target directories are called "build", then you can write this in gitingnore:

```
[Bb]uild/
```

This should solve the problem. From the documentation:

> If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but it would only find a match with a directory. In other words, foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link foo (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in Git).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Just one more query though, if I wanted to ignore all the file with specific name like a.out. How to do it .gitignore file?

Comment: You can specify in a file "a.out" -  for all files in a project with an EXACT name "a.out" or you can specify "*.out" to exclude all files of the format ".out"